# No getter/setter on model with many instance vars

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns

While reading [Object calisthenics](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/#no-classes-with-more-than-two-instance-variables) and [Getters/Setters. Evil. Period.](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html) I got confused. Let me explain it by example.

I have this organization class, representing the information about organization, the classic entity:

```
class Organization
{
    private $name;

    private $city;

    private $street;

    private $phone;

    private $email;

    public function __construct($name, $city, $street, $phone, $email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->street = $street;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        ....
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        ....
    }

    public function setCity($newCity)
    {
        ....
    }

    public function getStreet()
    {
        ....
    }

    public function setStreet($newStreet)
    {
        ....
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        ....
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        ....
    }

    public function setPhone($newPhoneNumber)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

The organization name, city, street, phone and email may change, so the setters looks kind a logical. Getters are used to to display the properties of organization in table. How can I remove the boilerplate code and break trough from this anemic model? Maybe this is the case where the getter/setter is unavoidable?

Also object initialization using `__construct`. Is it a good practice to pass so many instance variables to constructor?

I gave it a try, according to what I read. Created some `ValueObject` to store information and do validation (don't know if the `ValueObject` should do a validation on its data):

```
class Phone
{
    private $phone;

    public function __construct($phone)
    {
        if (!$this->validate($phone)) {
            throw new InvalidPhoneNumberException();
        }

        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    private function validate($phone)
    {
        // validate the phone number
    }
}

class Email
{
    private $email;

    public function __construct($email)
    {
        if (!$this->validate($email)) {
            throw new InvalidEmailAddressException();
        }

        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    private function validate($email)
    {
        // validate email
    }
}


class Address
{
    private $city;

    private $street;

    public function __construct($city, $street)
    {
        $this->city= $city;
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }
}
```

Then passed these objects instead of string representations of data to my Organization and did some renaming on methods:

```
class Organization
{
    private $name;

    private $address;

    private $phone;

    private $email;

    public function __construct($name, Address $address, Phone $phone, Email $email)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->phone = $phone;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function changeAddress(Address $newAddress)
    {
        $this->address = $newAddress;
    }

    public function changePhoneNumber(Phone $newPhoneNumber)
    {
        $this->phone = $newPhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Does this code smells less and looks more mature from the perspective of OOP?

Answer (score 1):

### Getters and setters are not evil, period.

Mindlessly setting and getting fields of an **object** is bad, though. Especially with this syntax (setX, getX).

Simple example showing the difference between mindless and thoughtful setter :

```
# Mindless
class CartesianPoint {
    private $x;
    private $y;

    public function setX($x) {
        $this->x = $x;
    }

    public function setY($y) {
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}

# Thoughtful
class CartesianPoint {
    private $x;
    private $y;

    public function plot($x, $y) {
        $this->x = $x;
        $this->y = $y;
    }
}
```

Can you spot the differences ? You don't want to be able to **only** set X or Y location of a cartesian point, because that is not **how it works**.

Note that object is written in bold in the second sentence. Your `Organization` class is merely a data structure here. There's no sense attached to it, it doesn't follow rules and doesn't use its own logic.

In conclusion, if something has some logic/sense about it that the external world knows (should know) nothing about, make an object, but so far, `Organization` should only have public fields, and absolutely no methods inside. That's not an object.

Answer (score 0):

I like that you are considering your `Address`, `Email`, and `Phone` objects as being immutable.  That is, if you needed to change one of these on the `Organization` object, you would simply discard the old reference for a new one.

As you rightfully stated, using these classes makes it **much** easier to simplify code where these dependencies are being used, as you can enforce the dependency via type-hinting, and skip all the guarding clauses.

With regards to the question around whether to write getters/setters, I think your approach is fine.  There are a couple of other approaches you might consider to find what works best for your application's needs:

Use magic methods defined in a trait or base class to provide immutability to classes that use/extend on this functionality.

Trait example:

```
trait ReadOnlyMagicAccessors
{
    public function __get($prop) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop) {
            throw new Exception("I don't have that property!");
        }
        return $this->$prop;
    }

    public function __set($prop, $value) {
        throw new Exception('I am immutable!');
    }

    public function __isset($prop) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop) {
            throw new Exception("I don't have that property!");
        }
        return isset($this->prop);
    }         
}

class Phone
{
    use ReadOnlyMagicAccessors;

    private $phone;

    public function __construct($phone)
    {
        if (!$this->validate($phone)) {
            throw new InvalidPhoneNumberException();
        }

        $this->phone = $phone;
    }

    // no need for getter here anymore

    private function validate($phone)
    {
        // validate the phone number
    }
}
```

This would allow property-style access to callers (i.e. `$phone->phone`), which some developers prefer.

Another approach might also use a trait which presents a standard accessor like `$class->get('key')`.

```
Trait GetAccessor {
    public function get($prop) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop) {
            throw new Exception("I don't have that property!");
        }
        return $this->$prop;
    }
}
```

The trait would be `use`d in the class similarly to the first example.

Another thing I might suggest is to think about your `Organization` entity and how it interacts in your system.

- Should it really be immutable?
- Should it be capable of holding one-to-many relationships with addresses, emails, and phone numbers?
- Do you need to validate `$name` in your constructor?

Finally, I don't like `change*` naming convention as you are doing a simple set operation here. I think `set*` would be more standard nomenclature for what is happening here.